# Inject Keystrokes

Tags: android, automated-tests, keyboard

Is there a way to inject keystrokes into the JVM on the Android platform?

I'm looking for something like `java.awt.Robot` but I don't think that's available on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm actually working on a Synergy port to the android (synergy-foss.org) and I think the best (and only method) for faking out keystrokes on the device itself is to write to /dev/input/uinput.  However it seems this is only available with Cyanogen mod

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need InstrumentationTestCase.sendKeys()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#sendKeys(java.lang.String)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: This works a treat in test cases when you have properly instantiated `Instrumentation` object but don't try to use this in the normal running of your app, as it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$ adb -s <serialno> emu event send <event>
```

where the event description can be something like:

```
"EV_KEY:KEY_A:1"
```